# SELECT specific fields inside the MySQL JSON Column datatype using bookshelf or Knex ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

Suppose I have the following MySQL table structure:

==========================================================
| id | name |                 address                     |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

### | 1  | Dawn | {"state": "Maryland", "city": "Annapolis"}  |

## | 2  | Pablo| {"state": "Ohio", "city": "Columbus"}       |

The address column is of json type. I use the bookshelf and the knex ORM in my application, I need to do query so that it will fetch name and the state name without city.
My plain SQL query will look like this:

select  name, address->"$.state"
from user

OR

select  name, json_extract(address, "$.state")
from user

But when I do it using Bookshelf:
user.select('name', 'address->"$.state"').fetch().then(....)

I'm getting an invalid error in SQL command due to the quote and backtick format.
The SQL generated using bookshelf is as below:

> select 'address->\" '.'state\" ', 'name' from `user.

Any suggestions to avoid the backtick mark issue around Dot(.) character ?? Or some other way of approach??

PS: This just an example

Comment: @andrewmclagan You might be helpful here!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate those queries like this:

```
// select name, address->"$.state" from user
knex('user').select('name', knex.raw('??->"$.state"', ['address']))

// select name, json_extract(address, "$.state") from user
knex('user').select('name', knex.raw('json_extract(??, "$.state")', ['address']))
```